# Getting Chrome's Download Directory With ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have been working with Selenium ChromeDriver and need for my python script to find the directory where Chrome downloads to. So my script grabs a bunch of files from a site and then works with those files, but different users have set different download directories, so is there an easy way to get this information? I saw [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) the chromeObject class has a prefs method, but whenever I import chromedriver it doesn't include this class. Am I missing something? Do I need to import an additional module?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: out of curiosity what are you needing to do with the files?

Comment: They are CSV's and I need to use their data for other processes.

Comment: the prefs method there is an extension of the Map<> class that was so not really something chromedriver specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a could approaches to this.  On windows 7 at lease chrome defaults to the users download directory so something like this: C:\Users[username]\Downloads.  So you could just code that paths into your test.  Another option would be to create a specific test profile that specifies a specific path and you can specify it in the options to use that profile:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

A third option would be to skip all the file IO stuff and use a web proxy tool to intercept the package and just deal with the data in code.  This is an approach I have taken before though in c#.

Comment: I guess it would make more sense to just set the directory rather than trying to hunt down the user's current download directory. Thanks!